# Stop Pi from searching for ethernet connection on startup

Tags: raspbian, networking, ethernet

I have three possible internet connections on my pi:

eth0 (unused)
wlan0 - a cheapo dongle 
usb0 - my Android phone.

When I switch on my Pi, it searches for an ethernet connection for a long time, which, seeing as it's disconnected, never happens.

It repeatedly spits out the result...

`DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval...`

...over and over again for about 1-2 minutes, before booting normally. Whilst this isn't a problem *per se*, it is annoying and simply slows me down. Seeing as I'm trying to use the Pi in a very portable configuration, this is a bit of a nark.

Does anybody know how to stop this happening?

Thanks!

P.S. I'm on Raspbian Wheezy

Comment: Do you need to disable completely `eth0`, or you just want to make it discovering the network only if the other interfaces failed?

Comment: I don't want to disable it, I just don't want it to bother looking for an ethernet connection at all on startup

Answer (score 5):

I have my own answer. Again. I have to stop asking I think.

As suggested above, I needed to edit the `/etc/network/interfaces`, but I just changed `auto eth0` to `auto wlan0` so it picks up the wifi instead.

Comment: You mean in `/etc/network/interface`, right?

Comment: Yes, I do, sorry, will clarify...

Answer (score 4):

Simple! Go to `/etc/network/interface` and add:

```
auto eth0
iface inet eth0 manual
```

And reboot.

Comment: It's still doing it :/

Answer (score 3):

There is a option on the raspi configurations to NOT wait for a ethernet connection to establish and just boot normaly. Its a checkbox. Hope it helps someone